# How to add default attribute value of "class" in custom htmlhelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I try to create a custom textbox in mvc. I want to add default class value *"text-uppercase"*.I also want add new class values in view.

Myhelper class is;

```
public static MvcHtmlString Custom_TextBox<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {

        ModelMetadata oModelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        if (htmlAttributes == null)
        {
            htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        htmlAttributes.Add("type", "text");
        htmlAttributes.Add("name", oModelMetadata.DisplayName);
        htmlAttributes.Add("id", oModelMetadata.DisplayName);
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", "text-uppercase");


        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

And my view code:

```
   @Html.Custom_TextBox(model => model.YazilimAdi,new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Actually  the error is: An item with the same key has already been added. "class".

How can i add my default class value "text-uppercase"?

Comment: You can check if the htmlAttributes dictionary already contains the key "class".  If so, append your default class if it isn't already present.

Comment: Your have already used `htmlAttributes.Add("class", "text-uppercase");` so you cannot then add `class = "form-control` via the attributes. Instead add the class name to the existing attributes if it already exists in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("class"))
{
    htmlAttributes["class"] += " text-uppercase";
}
else
{
    htmlAttributes.Add("class", "text-uppercase");
}
```

and put this at the beginning of extension:

```
if (htmlAttributes == null)
{
    htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```